# Nagiosgraph onMouseOver not working

Tags: javascript, apache, cgi, nagios

I had a nagios server monitoring several hosts and services. Now I've been asked to implement nagiosgraph. I've followed the documentation to the letter and everything worked except the mouse over function.

I created a common-header.ssi file with this code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/nagiosgraph/nagiosgraph.js"></script>
```

I've placed this file into my nagios path /usr/local/nagios/share/ssi

I've defined a service to work out with the mouse over function like this:

```
define service{
    use                             local-service,graphed-service
    host_name                       TOMCAT-DESARROLLO
    service_description             Tomcat heap memory
    check_command                   check_nrpe!check_jmx_heap
    notifications_enabled           0
    action_url                      /nagiosgraph/cgi-bin/show.cgi?host=$HOSTNAME$&service=$SERVICEDESC$' onMouseOver="showGraphPopup(this)" onMouseOut="hideGraphPopup()" rel='/nagiosgraph/cgi-bin/showgraph.cgi?host=$HOSTNAME$&service=$SERVICEDESC$
}
```

Nagiosgraphs works properly, I can access graphs for a service clicking on the icon. When I mouse over the icon, a popup should show the graph without needing to click anywhere, but instead I get this error message in the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: showGraphPopup is not defined
     onmouseover @ status.cgi?host=all:893
```

It seems to me that nagiosgraph is using the wrong cgi, since the command line states it would be using "showgraph.cgi" but the error is coming from nagios' "status.cgi".

Any ideas on why would this be happening and how to fix it?

Thanks a lot

Comment: This is the documentation I've been following is the very same included in the nagiosgrap-1.5.2.tar.gz package.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is relevant to U any more, I battled with same issue for 2 days now and finally got it.
From Nagios: `You can include custom headers and footers in the output of the CGIs by dropping some appropriately named HTML files in the ssi/ subdirectory of the Nagios HTML directory (i.e. /usr/local/nagios/share/ssi).`
Not true! The format of the ssi files should be in bash not HTML. Meaning you should echo output. Example common-header.ssi:

```
#!/bin/bash    
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/nagiosgraph/nagiosgraph.js\"></script>"
```